# Alternative datatype for ident and varchar(max)

Tags: sap-ase

I am converting a SQL stored procedure to Sybase ASE.

I came cross some datatypes like:

```
declare @mask ident
declare @type ident
declare @start varchar(max)
```

`Ident` and `varchar(max)` are not supported in Sybase ASE. What will be the correct alternative datatype which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sybase ASE, the value for a *varchar* can be anything up to the pagesize of the server (2k,4k,8k or 16k are the available page sizes.)

Sybase doesn't have an ident datatype, but you can create a user defined datatype that can be used instead.

```
sp_addtype ident, "numeric(5)", "identity"
```

There's more information here, in Sybase's [Transact-SQL User's Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug318.htm)

Comment: Thanks Michael..Do we have any alternative for text datatype ?

Comment: *text* is a valid datatype, so no alternative is necessary.

Comment: I m able to use text datatype only while creating table. It is not supported as parameter to stored procedure..Geeting exception if i try to create SP with text datatype. "TEXT,UNITEXT,IMAGE datatypes are invalid for parameters or local variables..sybase error code:2739 "